# VBO copy Field Decimal

Tags: views

I need to copy a value of one field to a decimal filed. When I try to do this with VBO and a token [node:price] I get an error: Only numbers and the decimal separator. Is there a way to copy fields into a decimal data type?

Comment: I ended up just creating a view with the existing data I wanted. I then exported the data into a CSV. I then used excel to clean the data and https://www.drupal.org/project/feed_import to pull the data I wanted back into the database. I was able to also update several fields with varchar type using vbo but the decimal type is still and issue. I tried doing the Execute arbitrary PHP script method described here https://www.drupal.org/node/1000200 but my code resulted in just a 0$

Comment: code mentioned above that did not work:
$entity->field_raised_to_date_[$entity->language][0]['nid'] = $entity->field_raised_to_date_3[$entity->language][0]['nid'];
node_save($entity);
I was able to accomplish what I needed but am still interested to see if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would just add a quick jquery script myself that converts to the right format and autofills it into the field on the 'change' event.

I dont know your level of expertise on jquery, but if needed i can provide you a small example